# add_axes with no frame

Tags: matplotlib, frame, axes

I'm trying to insert an axis inside a plot but without the frame. Somehow the options do not work at all

I have the following mwe

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

iax = AA.Axes(f, [0.125, 0.125, 0.775, 0.2], frameon=False)
f.add_axes(iax, frameon=False)
iax.set_yticks([]), iax.set_xticks([])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of using `matplotlib.axisartist` is not clear from the question. To obtain a frameless axes you may use `figure.add_axes([..], frameon=False)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

iax = f.add_axes([0.125, 0.125, 0.775, 0.2], frameon=False)
iax.set_yticks([]), iax.set_xticks([])
iax.plot(range(10),[i%4 for i in range(10)])

plt.show()
```